# How to convert a voltage source into a current source when resistors are in series?

Tags: circuit-analysis

I am following the diagram that is attached below:

[image]

Now, say I have the following circuit:

[image]

And I apply this theorem and end up with [image]

Then, even though the current was the same in Circuit B for R, R1, R2; it is generally different for R than for R1 and R2 in circuit A. Why is this?

Comment: good question. +1

Answer (score 1, accepted):

It's because the theorem about equivalence of Thevenin and Norton sources states only that the currents and voltages in **the external circuit** (i.e. anything to the right of points (A) and (B) in your circuit) are the same.

Not the voltage across or currents through the series/parallel resistors of the equivalent Thevenin/Norton sources. Those resistors belong to the sources.

I.e. in this case only currents/voltages at R1 and R2 are the same; not currents/voltages at R.

This fact that current/voltage at R can't be the same is obvious if you assume your external circuit to be e.g. an open circuit (or a short circuit):
if the external circuit is an open circuit the current through R of a Thevenin
source is 0; the current through R of an equivalent Norton source not.